# SD card reader not detected by Linux kernel 5.3

Tags: opensuse, hardware, sd-card

My laptop's SD card reader is recognized by Linux (OpenSUSE Tumbleweed) as "RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader", yet it is not visible by the system when I insert an SD card (tried it with SD cards of different sizes, including sizes less than 1 GB). I think if it worked and I could mount it, I could see something like `mmblkXXXX` with this command:

```
int@linux-pc54:~/Downloads> ll /dev | grep mm
crw-------   1 root root       10, 165 Oct 13 03:59 vmmon
```

which doesn't happen.

So I'm wondering if there is a solution to this. Would appreciate some help.
I've also tried it with Megeia 7 an the latest CentOS 7 (including CentOS Stream), to no avail.

Comment: Could you post the output of `dmesg` and `lsblk` (relevant parts) after inserting a card?

Comment: It would need the driver enabled too: https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/MISC_RTSX_PCI.html . The option changed name after 4.15, maybe the distribution didn't notice?

Comment: @A.B It doesn't seem that it is described on that page how to enable that driver.

Comment: @rudib `sudo dmesg | grep Realtek` does not return anything relevant to the SD card reader. OpenSUSE's own YaST Hardware gives the information that the reader is RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader and the associated driver `rtsx_pci`. `lsblk` only shows the local hard disk (sdai, where i=1,2,3,4). It is notable that this card reader works well with Manjaro on kernel 5.3.

Comment: @sequence you have to verify if this driver is enabled in your kernel, usually by checking /boot/config* 's content. Can you add in your question the result of `grep CONFIG_MISC_RTSX_PCI /boot/config*` ?

Comment: @A.B Here's the output: https://pastebin.com/raw/wiG73BNg

Comment: ok so you have the kernel module and I'm thus out of clues

Comment: @sequence you could try unplugging it, then plugging it in again and follow up with `dmesg | tail` a few seconds later. You should get some output regarding the detection (and driver assignment) of the device.

Comment: @rudib It is a built-in card reader.

Comment: @sequence I see. Sorry, I read over the "PCI" part. Maybe `lspci` can help?

Comment: @rudib `sudo lspci | grep Realtek` gives the following: `54:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)`. Do you know what the word "Unassigned" might mean in this context?

Comment: @sequence apparently, you are supposed to use `rtsx_usb`: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=124956#p595032

Comment: @rudib I tried `sudo modprobe rtsx_usb`, but to no avail. I've also added `rtsx_usb` to `/etc/modules-load.d/sdcardreader.conf` to see what happens after I reboot. Is this where I should put it?

Comment: Maybe remove `rtsx_pci` by running `modprobe -r rtsx_pci` and then insert `rtsx_usb`? And maybe also check `dmesg` after doing that.

Comment: @rudib Tried this, `sudo dmesg| grep rtsx` produces this: https://pastebin.com/raw/gjNB6P33
Reinserting an SD card produces no reaction from the OS.

Comment: @ok, please use `grep -A 10 -B 5 rtsx` or something along those lines. Not every related entry will contain `rtsx`. You may also want to grep for `usbcore`.

Comment: @rudib Here's the output: https://pastebin.com/raw/sCxtByXV, https://pastebin.com/raw/AQBeJXMr What do you think?

Comment: Hmm sorry, I still have no clue - But what is your `uname -a`? Apparently, there was [a bug](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/laptop-not-recognizing-realtek-rts525a-pci-express-card-reader/54800/9) until 5.3. Also, if you are using `systemd`, `journalctl -b` could also tell you more.

Comment: `uname -a` says 5.3.5. `journalctl -b` says this: https://pastebin.com/raw/iT0Ks9mW. Yet, `sudo lspci | grep Real` gives this: `54:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)`.

Comment: @sequence `journalctl -b | grep Realtek`? Sorry that I'm just asking for `grep`s, but that error is very silent... You could also try to use `rtsx_pci` and remove and add it a few times as this answer suggests: https://askubuntu.com/a/531426/834547 (not exactly the same model)

Comment: @rudib No problem at all, I appreciate your effort to help with this issue. Here's what `journalctl` returns: https://pastebin.com/2TsnvS58 Unfortunately, inserting and removing the driver several times with `modprobe` yieldded no result.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `rtsx_pci` might be blacklisted. Since that can happen in different ways a fulltext search of your module name across /etc is your best bet.

```
grep -r rtsx_pci /etc
```

I found my blacklist entry in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rts5227-dkms.conf` my Arch Linux system with Kernel 6.1 but I'm not exactly sure how it got there.